# Route multiple IPv6 /64 subnets of a VPC to a single AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

If I have an AWS VPC with an IPv6 prefix of `2001:db8:abc:de00::/56` allocated to it, how do I route the entirety of **two** /64 subnets to an EC2 instance?

```
VPC:      2001:db8:abc:de00::/56
Subnet 1: 2001:db8:abc:de11::/64
Subnet 2: 2001:db8:abc:de12::/64

EC2: Subnet 1 + Subnet 2
```

I want the EC2 instance to be able to send and receive traffic from **any** of the address inside of Subnet 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just add those entry in the EC2 route table, and put the EC2 eni in the route target.

I've just verified it's working inside a VPC.

In theory it should be working with an ingress routing table (a routing table with an edge association to an IGW), but it seems not working. I highly suspect it's a bug.

Comment: You may also use prefix delegation instead: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-prefix-eni.html